# Adding an image into a GUI made with Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I'm still pretty new to Java, and in our programming class we are working in a group. My part of the assignment is to insert an image at the top part of the GUI.

this is the code I have so far..

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("EXTS.png"));
    JPanel.add(image, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

but right under the .add part of the Jpanel.add is that red squiggly line telling me that I should change my Image to a component and when I do that it tells me to switch it back to an Image?? this is what I'm getting confused on why would it tell me to change it back if it won't use it the way it is now?
So I guess my question is what should I do to fix this problem?

Also exactly how would I position it, I know it goes into the layout spot in the North but will that be dead center? or does it start from the 0,0 top left and then pixel in?

Thank you in advanced!

(P.s. this is the path to the image file if it should be different please tell me otherwise it's fine -- Project 3/Images/EXTS.png)

Comment: Read the tutorials -- you can **set** a JLabel with an ImageIcon, not a JPanel by calling the label's `setIcon(...)` method. Then add the JLabel to your JPanel. But don't guess at this stuff (as you're doing) as that never works. The tutorials are easy to find -- simply Google, Java Swing Tutorial, and check the first hit.

Comment: I'm not actually guessing, I went as far as to buy the Java for Dummies book which has been a great help on certain feature's I didn't understand. I have googled similar questions about adding pictures and everyone comes up with this similar code..

Comment: *"I have googled similar questions about adding pictures and everyone comes up with this similar code."*  Provide links for 3 of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Icon is not a component. You need to add the Icon to a component like a `JLabel`:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("EXTS.png"));
//JPanel.add(image, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JPanel.add(new JLabel(image), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the path to the image is correct, you should use a `JLabel` to show the image. See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details.

I'd also consider using `ImageIO` to read the image instead of `ImageIcon` as `ImageIO` will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more deatils

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(
            ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/EXTS.png")));
JPanel.add(new JLabel(image), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```